# Why does the DeserializeXmlNode output XML enclose array elements in an extra tag?

Tags: json, xml, json.net, deserialization

I have the following JSON I am converting to XML:

```
{
  "root": {
    "object": [{
      "Name": "Cust1",
      "addresses": [
        [{
          "AddressLine1": "Address1",
          "AddressLine2": "Address2"
        }],
        [{
          "AddressLine1": "Address3",
          "AddressLine2": "Address4"
        }]
      ]
    }, {
      "Name": "Cust2",
      "addresses": [
        [{
          "AddressLine1": "Address1_2",
          "AddressLine2": "Address2_2"
        }],
        [{
          "AddressLine1": "Address3_2",
          "AddressLine2": "Address4_2"
        }]
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```

I use the following code to convert it to the XML (the root element has been added manually after the JSON was converted):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(rootJson);
```

The output XML is as follows:

```
<root>
<object>
    <Name>Cust1</Name>
    <addresses>
        <addresses>
            <AddressLine1>Address1</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>Address2</AddressLine2>
        </addresses>
    </addresses>
    <addresses>
        <addresses>
            <AddressLine1>Address3</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>Address4</AddressLine2>
        </addresses>
    </addresses>
</object>
<object>
    <Name>Cust2</Name>
    <addresses>
        <addresses>
            <AddressLine1>Address1_2</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>Address2_2</AddressLine2>
        </addresses>
    </addresses>
    <addresses>
        <addresses>
            <AddressLine1>Address3_2</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>Address4_2</AddressLine2>
        </addresses>
    </addresses>
</object>
```

The problem is with the `<addresses>` tag which is followed by another `<addresses>` tag.

Comment: It seems like there's an extra level of JSON array nesting -- `[[{ "AddressLine1": "Address1", "AddressLine2": "Address2"}]]` instead of `[{ "AddressLine1": "Address1", "AddressLine2": "Address2"}]`.  That probably causes the extra level of XML nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have an extra `[` and `]` below

```
  "addresses": [
    [{
      "AddressLine1": "Address1",
      "AddressLine2": "Address2"
    }],
    [{
      "AddressLine1": "Address3",
      "AddressLine2": "Address4"
    }]
  ]
```

If you remove the extra `[` and `]` like below

```
  "addresses": [
    {
      "AddressLine1": "Address1",
      "AddressLine2": "Address2"
    },
    {
      "AddressLine1": "Address3",
      "AddressLine2": "Address4"
    }
  ]
```

Your json will be like this

```
{
  "root": {
    "object": [{
      "Name": "Cust1",
      "addresses": [
        {
          "AddressLine1": "Address1",
          "AddressLine2": "Address2"
        },
        {
          "AddressLine1": "Address3",
          "AddressLine2": "Address4"
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "Name": "Cust2",
      "addresses": [
        {
          "AddressLine1": "Address1_2",
          "AddressLine2": "Address2_2"
        },
        {
          "AddressLine1": "Address3_2",
          "AddressLine2": "Address4_2"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```

and you'll get the following output XML

```
<root>
  <object>
    <Name>Cust1</Name>
    <addresses>
      <AddressLine1>Address1</AddressLine1>
      <AddressLine2>Address2</AddressLine2>
    </addresses>
    <addresses>
      <AddressLine1>Address3</AddressLine1>
      <AddressLine2>Address4</AddressLine2>
    </addresses>
  </object>
  <object>
    <Name>Cust2</Name>
    <addresses>
      <AddressLine1>Address1_2</AddressLine1>
      <AddressLine2>Address2_2</AddressLine2>
    </addresses>
    <addresses>
      <AddressLine1>Address3_2</AddressLine1>
      <AddressLine2>Address4_2</AddressLine2>
    </addresses>
  </object>
</root>
```

Working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Oyj91s